# TypeScript Optional Parameters not working

Tags: typescript

I have this `SampleData` class with a default property `prop2`.

```
class SampleData {
   prop1: string;
   prop2: {} = {};
 }

 export default SampleData;
```

When I create `SampleData` without `prop2`, it returns compilation error.

> Argument of type '{ prop1: string; }' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'SampleData'.   Type '{ prop1: string; }' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'SampleData': message, data

```
class Test {

  constructor() {
     this.method1({ prop1: 'asdf' })
  }

  method1(data: SampleData) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For optional parameters, use `?` while defining your models.

```
class SampleData {
   prop1: string;
   prop2?: {} = {};
}
```